# Exact solution for $u_t+v(t)u_x=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Is the analytical solution for scalar coefficient $c$ as $u(x,t)=u(x-ct,0)$ for $u_t+cu_x=0$ work same manner for the time-dependent coefficient case $u_t+v(t)u_x=0$ with the method of characteristics? or is there a different method?

Want to solve
\begin{equation}
   u_t+v(t)u_x = 0    
\end{equation}
with a given Initial condition
\begin{equation}
   u(x,0) = f(x)    
\end{equation}
and $v$ comes from a Solution to an ODE in time as
\begin{equation}
   v_t = -\frac{1}{\int_0^1 u dx}\Bigg[ \frac{1}{3A}\Bigg(\int_0^1(\rho-1)dx\Bigg)+B v|v|\int_0^1 u dx\Bigg]   
\end{equation}
with $v(0)=1$ and $A,B$ real constants

Comment: The method used for solving any partial differential equation depends on the boundary values that are known. Please write down your boundary conditions so we can answer your question.

Comment: The same method can be used, but when the velocity $v$ is not constant you no longer have that the distance we travel in time $t$ is just $vt$ (what is it?). If you apply the method then this will drop out naturally.

Comment: @Winther, Thank you for the explanation. $v$ is the velocity and $u$ is some property of the the flow. So can I directly take the solution as $u(x-vt,0)$ in this case? Its not clear to me what you said that "this will drops naturally"

Comment: Try to apply the actual method and you will see that you *almost* get the same solution, only with the exception that the $-vt$ term is slightly different (and the difference is just what I mentioned above).

Comment: @Winther  with the parameter $s$ arrived at characteristic curves $dt/ds=1, dx/ds=v(t), du/ds=0$. I can get only $dx/dt=v(t)$ and after that, I'm kind of lost on how to follow the procedure to achieve the solution.

Comment: $$\frac{dx}{dt} = v(t) \implies x - \int v(t) dt = C_{1}$$

Comment: @MatthewCassell ok so then $du/dt=0$ i get $u=C_2$ and joining the parameter families $C_2=g(C_1)$ for an arbitrary $g$. Then $u(x,t)=g(x-\int v(t)dt)$, And since initially $u(x,0)=g(x)=f(x)$ and $g$ is arbitrary $u(x,t)=f(x-\int v(t)dt)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Very good, yes that is correct. Just missing some integration limits: since $u(x,0) = f(x)$ you need the integral to be $\int_0^t v(t') dt'$ (so that it vanishes at $t=0$).

Comment: @Winther Thank you for your comments. It helps me a lot.

Comment: @MatthewCassell; Thank you very much for your feedback as well.